# SageMaker Batch Transform fails to access nginx

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, nginx-config

I had been trying to deploy a ML model on SageMaker using Docker.
So far I have been able to run the Training job, however the model inference using batch transform is having issue with nginx log:
[image]

The nginx.conf file has the following:

```
worker_processes 1;
daemon off; # Prevent forking


pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
  # defaults
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
  
  upstream gunicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080 deferred;
    client_max_body_size 5m;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    proxy_read_timeout 1200s;

    location ~ ^/(ping|invocations) {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://gunicorn;
    }

    location / {
      return 404 "{}";
    }
  }
}
```

And the 'serve' file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# This file implements the scoring service shell. You don't necessarily need to modify it for various
# algorithms. It starts nginx and gunicorn with the correct configurations and then simply waits until
# gunicorn exits.
#
# The flask server is specified to be the app object in wsgi.py
#
# We set the following parameters:
#
# Parameter                Environment Variable              Default Value
# ---------                --------------------              -------------
# number of workers        MODEL_SERVER_WORKERS              the number of CPU cores
# timeout                  MODEL_SERVER_TIMEOUT              60 seconds

import multiprocessing
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import sys

cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

model_server_timeout = os.environ.get('MODEL_SERVER_TIMEOUT', 60)
model_server_workers = int(os.environ.get('MODEL_SERVER_WORKERS', cpu_count))

def sigterm_handler(nginx_pid, gunicorn_pid):
    try:
        os.kill(nginx_pid, signal.SIGQUIT)
    except OSError:
        pass
    try:
        os.kill(gunicorn_pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    except OSError:
        pass

    sys.exit(0)

def start_server():
    print('Starting the inference server with {} workers.'.format(model_server_workers))


    # link the log streams to stdout/err so they will be logged to the container logs
    subprocess.check_call(['ln', '-sf', '/dev/stdout', '/var/log/nginx/access.log'])
    subprocess.check_call(['ln', '-sf', '/dev/stderr', '/var/log/nginx/error.log'])

    nginx = subprocess.Popen(['nginx', '-c', '/opt/program/nginx.conf'])
    gunicorn = subprocess.Popen(['gunicorn',
                                 '--timeout', str(model_server_timeout),
                                 '-k', 'sync',
                                 '-b', 'unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock',
                                 '-w', str(model_server_workers),
                                 'wsgi:app'])

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda a, b: sigterm_handler(nginx.pid, gunicorn.pid))

    # If either subprocess exits, so do we.
    pids = set([nginx.pid, gunicorn.pid])
    while True:
        pid, _ = os.wait()
        if pid in pids:
            break

    sigterm_handler(nginx.pid, gunicorn.pid)
    print('Inference server exiting')

# The main routine just invokes the start function.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()
```

I have predictor.py that has flask handler as below:

```
# This is the file that implements a flask server to do inferences. It's the file that you will modify to
# implement the scoring for your own algorithm.

from __future__ import print_function

import io
import json
import os
import pickle
import signal
import sys
import traceback

import flask
import pandas as pd

prefix = "/opt/ml/"
model_path = os.path.join(prefix, "model")

# A singleton for holding the model. This simply loads the model and holds it.
# It has a predict function that does a prediction based on the model and the input data.


class ScoringService(object):
    model = None  # Where we keep the model when it's loaded

    @classmethod
    def get_model(cls):
        """Get the model object for this instance, loading it if it's not already loaded."""
        if cls.model == None:
            with open(os.path.join(model_path, "_logreg_cap.pkl"), "rb") as inp:
                cls.model = pickle.load(inp)
        return cls.model

    @classmethod
    def predict(cls, input):
        """For the input, do the predictions and return them.

        Args:
            input (a pandas dataframe): The data on which to do the predictions. There will be
                one prediction per row in the dataframe"""
        clf = cls.get_model()
        return clf.predict(input)


# The flask app for serving predictions
app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/ping", methods=["GET"])
def ping():
    """Determine if the container is working and healthy. In this sample container, we declare
    it healthy if we can load the model successfully."""
    health = ScoringService.get_model() is not None  # You can insert a health check here

    status = 200 if health else 404
    return flask.Response(response="\n", status=status, mimetype="application/json")


@app.route("/invocations", methods=["POST"])
def transformation():
    """Do an inference on a single batch of data. In this sample server, we take data as CSV, convert
    it to a pandas data frame for internal use and then convert the predictions back to CSV (which really
    just means one prediction per line, since there's a single column.
    """
    data = None

    # Convert from CSV to pandas
    if flask.request.content_type == "text/csv":
        data = flask.request.data.decode("utf-8")
        s = io.StringIO(data)
        data = pd.read_csv(s, header=None)
    else:
        return flask.Response(
            response="This predictor only supports CSV data", status=415, mimetype="text/plain"
        )

    print("Invoked with {} records".format(data.shape[0]))

    # Do the prediction
    predictions = ScoringService.predict(data)

    # Convert from numpy back to CSV
    out = io.StringIO()
    pd.DataFrame({"results": predictions}).to_csv(out, header=False, index=False)
    result = out.getvalue()

    return flask.Response(response=result, status=200, mimetype="text/csv")
```

Any solution?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your container code as well? How is your Flask handler setup (app.py), this is where your actual inference code goes. Please follow this guide for BYOC: https://towardsdatascience.com/bring-your-own-container-with-amazon-sagemaker-37211d8412f4

Comment: I added a flask handler setup which was saved under predictor.py, I don't have app.py